# How can I verify whether an exception was thrown by WebFlux async call?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, mockito, spring-webflux

### Problem

I have a service which executes async request. The method itself does not return anything, although it has error handler. I would like to test whether this handler works properly.

##### Service

```
@Component
class MyService {

    val webClient: WebClient by lazy {
        WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("https://localhost:8080")
            .build()
    }

    fun send() {
        webClient.get()
            .uri("/posts")
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError) { Mono.error { MyException() } }
            .bodyToMono(Void::class.java)
            .subscribe()
    }
}
```

##### Test

Now in the test I've mocked server response:

```
@Test
fun test() {
    
    mockWebServer.enqueue(MockResponse()
        .setResponseCode(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value())
        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
    )

    myService.send()

    // Here I want to verify an exception was thrown
}
```

I could resolve the problem by changing `subscribe()` to `block()` but my goal is call the request asynchronousely and not to block call site.

Thank you for help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess instead of subscribing in the `send()` method, you could return the Mono and subscribe in the caller method, so in your test, you may use `.block()` to wait for the completion and handle the exception:

```kotlin
@Component
class MyService {

    val webClient: WebClient by lazy {
        WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("https://localhost:8080")
            .build()
    }

    fun send(): Mono<Void> {
        return webClient.get()
            .uri("/posts")
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError) { Mono.error { MyException() } }
            .bodyToMono(Void::class.java)
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@Test
fun test() {
    
    mockWebServer.enqueue(MockResponse()
        .setResponseCode(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value())
        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
    )

    assertThrows<MyException> {
        myService.send().block()
    }
}
```

And in your actual code where you do `myService.send()`, you may need to use `.subscribe()`, so the actual code remains non-blocking, and you're able to test the error handling painlessly